# Where are admob resource identifiers defined?

Tags: android, attributes, admob

In the old versions of admob SDK, you had to manually add a `attrs.xml` file where the admob attributes where defined (adUnitId,adSize etc..) But it is not necessary anymore in the current version of the SDK. The only thing you need to do in your XML layout file is to declare the admob namespace with xmlns.

So my question is: how did they manage to do that? I'm just curious about how they declared or defined these attributes; and I could actually use this "trick" to use with my customs views that have their own attributes in the future.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, AdMob is calling [AttributeSet.getAttributeValue(String namespace, String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html#getAttributeValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and similar methods. It passes in the namespace ("http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads") that it expects. This doesn't need to be a valid url - it should just be a unique one that doesn't conflict with other namespaces.

Comment: Thansk,  but it's not what I am looking for. What I would like to know is not how they get the attributes, but how they defined them without using an xml file such as attrs.xml :/

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think it's arbitrary. You could try defining `xmlns:mynamespace="http://www.mywebsite.com/app/com.my.namespace"`, and using `mynamespace:myvalue='Hello World'` in your XML. Then your code would try to call something like `AttributeSet.getAttributeValue("http://www.mywebsite.com/app/com.my.namespace", "myvalue")` to get this value.